# Jenkins pipeline using upstream and downstream dependency

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I had some jenkins standalone jobs to build, package and deploy. Now I am connecting them and making 'build' job trigger 'package' job , and 'package' job to trigger 'deploy' job and am passing the required parameters between them.I can also see them neatly in pipeline view.

My question is, can this technically be called a pipeline? Or can I call it a pipeline only if I use pipeline plugin and write groovy script?

Thanks
p.s: Please do not devote this question. It is a sincere question for which I am not able to find the right answer. I want to be technically correct.

Comment: Technically correct: the best kind of correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Jenkins context, a [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) is a job that defines a workflow using pipeline DSL (here, based on Groovy). A pipeline aims to define a bunch of steps (e.g. `build` + `package` + `deploy` in your case) in a single place, allows to define a complex workflow (e.g. `parallel` steps, `input` step, `try/catch` instructions) that can be both replayed and versionned (because it can be saved to git). For more information you should read [Jenkins official pipeline documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) that explains in details what a pipeline is.

The kind of jobs you are currently using are called `freestyle` jobs, and even if they do define a "flow" (by chaining jobs together), they cannot be called `pipelines` jobs.

In short, `pipelines` are jobs that use `pipeline plugin` and `groovy` script syntax to define the whole application lifecycle, and standard Jenkins 1.x jobs are called `freestyle` jobs.